# Django: How do I return data from db along with the foreign key entities to the user as JSON?

Tags: python, json, django

I have two models as such,

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    ....
```

and

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    Foo = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

I have a view that returns Foo objects as JSON,

```
def list_by_city(request, city):
    foo_list = Foo.objects.filter(city=city).values()
    return JsonResponse({"Foo": list(foo_list)})
```

But this returns only the attributes from Foo. I want to add the attributes from Bar as well, which are related to Foo. How do I do that?

**EDIT:** The resulting JSON should be somewhat like,

```
{
   "Foo":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"A",
         "city":"B",
         "Bars":[
            {
               "name":"A"
            },
            {
               "name":"B"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"C",
         "city":"B",
         "Bars":[
            {
               "name":"D"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use just the [serialization](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) component of [`Django Rest Framework`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). It provides a declarative serializer that is more flexible than the one in `Django`.

`models.py`:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ManyToManyField(Foo, related_name='bars')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

`serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Foo, Bar


class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('name',)


class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bars = BarSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('name', 'city', 'bars')
```

Which results in:

```
>>> s = FooSerializer(my_foo_object)
>>> s.data
{'bars': [OrderedDict([('name', 'B')]), OrderedDict([('name', 'A')])], 'city': 'Bangkok', 'name': 'Foo'}
```

To serialize a queryset or list of objects you can do `FooSerializer(Foo.objects.all(), many=True)`.

Comment: I get only the fields from `Foo` into the output, not those from `Bar`. The ouput looks like this, `[OrderedDict([('name', ' A '), ('city', 'B')]), .....`

Comment: Check your database. Have your foo and bar objects a relationship? You should also write the field ``Foo`` of the class ``Bar`` in lower case.

Comment: That capital character was added by mistake while changing the names in the question, it is correct in the code. I have an sqlite database file. I checked it, and it seems to be correct. There are three tables, foo, bar, and foo_bar.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to post the adjusted model class. Hang on a second and see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another item to the dictionary in the view with  this:

```
 def list_by_city(request, city):
        response_data = {}
        response_data['foo_list'] = Foo.objects.filter(city=city).values()
        response_data['bar_list'] = Foo.objects.filter(country=country).values()
        return JsonResponse(json.dumps(response_data))
```

Comment: I guess this would give two seperate lists. I want a list of `Bar` added into every `Foo`. I'll add an example into my question